# .NET 4.5 Metro Application DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I cant get `DependencyProperty.Register` to work.

It requires `(string, string, string, PropertyMetadata)` instead of `string, Type, Type, UIPropertyMeatdata)`...

I changed the UI-PropertyMetadata part but can't get string part of it to work. 
I tried `typeof(T).ToString()` and just `"T"` but it doesn't work.

My code looks like this

```
public ObservableCollection<RingSegment> RingSegments {
    get { return (ObservableCollection<RingSegment>)GetValue(RingSegmentsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RingSegmentsProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty RingSegmentsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "RingSegments", typeof(ObservableCollection<RingSegment>), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<RingSegment>()));
```

And errors that i get

`Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty.Register(string, string, string, Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyMetadata)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\aleksandar.toplek\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\Project - XX\XX\MainPage.xaml.cs 21  68  XX`

`Error  2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'string'   C:\Users\aleksandar.toplek\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\Project - XX\XX\MainPage.xaml.cs 22  20  XX`

`Error  3   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'string'   C:\Users\aleksandar.toplek\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\Project - XX\XX\MainPage.xaml.cs 22  63  XX`

-- EDIT --

When I do this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RingSegmentsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "RingSegments", "ObservableCollection<RingSegment>", "MainPage", new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<RingSegment>()));
```

Code compiles but throws exception in runtime

`A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

in file `XamplTypeIngo.g.cs`

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The type initializer for 'XX.MainPage' threw an exception.
  Source=mscorlib
  TypeName=XX.MainPage
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._RunClassConstructor(RuntimeType type)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(RuntimeTypeHandle type)
       at Disk_Visualizer.XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.RunInitializer() in c:\Users\aleksandar.toplek\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\Project - XX\XX\obj\Debug\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 277
  InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=Windows.UI.Xaml
       StackTrace:
            at Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty.Register(String name, String propertyTypeName, String ownerTypeName, PropertyMetadata typeMetadata)
            at Disk_Visualizer.MainPage..cctor() in c:\Users\aleksandar.toplek\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\Project - XX\XX\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 21
       InnerException:  
...
```

Comment: From the code, it seems like a bug. What type do you get when you assign the typeof(xxxx) to static members. And then what happens during compile?

Comment: Those errors are from compiler. I don't understand what you mean by `when you assign the typeof(xxxx) to static members`

Comment: Instead of saying typeof(MainPage) in the arguments, can you add a static member that the DependencyProperty can use in its arguments. It seems like the compiler thinks the typeof(xx) should be strings, I just wonder if it thinks the same thing for an explicitly declared member.

Comment: F1 led me to [MSND Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty.Register);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) Now, this means that compiler doesn't have a bug... but I can't get strings right. Anyone else having this problem? Nobody was working with DependencyPropertyes?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.register(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: @Ritch Melton Type isn't valid in this case...

Comment: Yea, I guess that's new. It sure seems like a bug. I'll be curious to see what an expert has to say. It does seem like you should be able to work around it.

Comment: Ahh here ya go: From your docs. The current implementation of dependency property registration has property type and owner type specified by name, as a string. In contrast, WPF and Silverlight specify property type and owner type as a Type object.

Comment: Here's the reference for the WinRT DependencyProperty class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyproperty%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Adam Maras - Yea, he says this a WPF project though. I'm confused.

Comment: @RitchMelton I think he had a WPF project, and he's converting it to WinRT/Metro.

Comment: @Adam Maras - That makes sense.

Comment: I'm very sorry for this... didn't even know it was winrt cause of similarity :|

Comment: Another nightmare and lots of changes in code, first it was wpf then silverlight and now its winrt and by the time you will get your app right there is going to be something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find the solution for this problem on

[Dependency Property declaration MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/4fed80a8-1343-41ca-8c27-b20a00689f65)

Answer (score 1):

OK. After observing a little more, I noticed, just as Aleksandar Toplek pointed out, it is the XamlTypeInfo.g.cs code responsible for instantiating types. It uses the IXamlType CreateXamlType method for BOTH XAML defined types and discovering defined Dependency Properties. I noticed this when I change my SelectedUser DP type from User to string. I also noticed one of my converters in this switch implementation. I figured it picked it up when I declared it in my resources.

So I experimented:

I referenced the namespace to my custom class:

```
xmlns:model="using:AccountManagement.Model"
```

I added a sample model to "register" this type into XamlTypeInfo.g.cs implementation:

```
<!--Sample Model-->
<model:User x:Key="sampleUser"/>

// Generates the following case in CreateXamlType 
case "AccountManagement.Model.User":
   userType = new XamlUserType(this, typeName, typeof(AccountManagement.Model.User), GetXamlTypeByName("Windows.Foundation.Object"));
   userType.Activator = Activate_1_User;
   xamlType = userType;
   break;
```

I run my code and the type for my DP is recognized and instantiated. That's only the first part. On my dependency property I have a CallBack to invoke some logic upon selection.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedUserProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedUser", typeof(User).FullName, typeof(UsersView).FullName,
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedUserChanged));
```

I set up my bindings:

```
<GridView 
   ... 
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, ElementName=root}"
/>
<!--root being my UserControl (x:Name="root")-->
```

But this did not invoke the CallBack. :(. I eventually got it working using a handler that assigns the dp, and at that assignment it does trigger the callback. This confirms that the DP was properly registered with the proper type.

Getting the binding to work the way I expect it to work, is my next challenge.

Hope this helps,

Andres Olivares

Answer (score 0):

We don't have support for the Custom Type property declaration in WinRT C#. But you can try this workaround.

This may solve the problem.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RingSegmentsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "RingSegments", "ObservableCollection<"Object>", "MainPage", new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<"Object>())
```

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong but I still get `XamplTypeIngo.g.cs` exception...

Answer (score 0):

I am also running into issues declaring a dependency property for a UserControl. Tried this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedUserProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedUser", typeof(User).FullName, typeof(UsersView).FullName,
        new PropertyMetadata(default(User), OnSelectedUserChanged));
```

Where User is a custom class and UsersView is a UserControl, but still get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in accountreader.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Hope this helps,

Andres Olivares

Answer (score 0):

Passing `"Object"` as `propertyTypeName` helped in my case

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("My", "Object", typeof(MyControl).FullName, new PropertyMetadata(null));
```